# CSS fix for percentage rounding areas

Tags: html, css, multiple-columns, rounding, percentage

So I have a grid split into three even columns which, when setting them each to 33.33% leaves a small gap at the end of the column due to rounding errors (mostly in Safari).

I've attempted fix this by giving the columns a little bit extra (33.5%) and hiding the last .5%. But it's not working. This is my code:

```
<div class="grid-outer">
    <div class="grid-inner">
         <div class="box" style="background: green"></div>
         <div class="box" style="background: red"></div>
         <div class="box" style="background: gray"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

—

```
.grid-outer {
    width: 100%;
    overflow: hidden;
    background: lightyellow;
}

.grid-inner {
    width: 100.5%;
    overflow: hidden;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    width: 33.5%;
    height: 20px;
 }
```

But it doesn't work as expected for some reason? Is my code correct?

JSFiddle here: https://jsfiddle.net/2snT4/

Comment: Leave containers at 100%, and set the width of boxes to 33.33333333%

Comment: Because that will give you 100.5% of 100.5% which is 101.0025%

Answer (score 0):

Your percentages are incorrect on the fiddle. However, with the correct percentages, rounding error exist in browsers. Firefox has a similar issue when centering DIVs. Some browsers handle it better (Chrome, for example). Only way I know for sure to get around it is to use a table, but that is really kinda messy and other disadvantages; not a good solution.

```css
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.grid-outer {
    width: 100%;
    background: lightyellow;
}

.grid-inner {
    width: 100%;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333333333%;
    height: 20px;
}
```

```html
<div class="grid-outer">
    <div class="grid-inner">
         <div class="box" style="background: green"></div>
         <div class="box" style="background: red"></div>
         <div class="box" style="background: gray"></div>
    </div>
</div>
```

```
body, html {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
}

.grid-outer {
    width: 100%;
    background: lightyellow;
}

.grid-inner {
    width: 100%;
}

.box {
    float: left;
    width: 33.33333333333%;
    height: 20px;
}
```